# Querying through a join table Rails 4 Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, join

I am trying to get an array of records through a join table.  I want to find All of one User's Favorites that are Blue, but that are "current".  User_Favorites can expire.  This is what I'm trying:

User.rb

```
has_many :user_favorites, dependent: :destroy
has_many :favorites, through: :user_favorites
```

Favorite.rb

```
has_many :user_favorites, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :user_favorites
```

UserFavorite.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :favorite

 scope :current_as_of, -> (date) do
    where('start_date <= ?',date).
    where('(end_date >= ? or end_date IS NULL)', date)
  end

  scope :blue, -> { where('self.favorite.color = ?','blue') }
```

class UsersController < ApplicationController

```
def profile
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 @blue_favorites = @user.user_favorites.current_as_of(Date.today).blue.all
end
```

This is the error I get:

```
There is an Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "favorite"
LINE 1: ...d_date >= '2015-10-06' or end_date IS NULL)) AND (Favorite.co...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "user_favorites".* FROM "user_favorites" WHERE "user_favorites"."user_id" = $1 AND (start_date <= '2015-10-06') AND ((end_date >= '2015-10-06' or end_date IS NULL)) AND (Favorite.color = 'blue')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in regards to this:

```
  scope :blue, -> { where('self.favorite.color = ?','blue') }
```

It looks like you're mixing up database and ruby syntax. The other problem too is that the query, at this point, has no idea what `favorite` is because it hasn't been joined yet. Try something like this instead:

```
  scope :blue, -> { joins(:favorite).where(favorites: {color: 'blue'}) }
```

Comment: I am getting this error now "There is an Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "favorite"
LINE 1: ...id" WHERE "user_favorites"."user_id" = $1 AND "favorite"."...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "user_favorites".* FROM "user_favorites" INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "favorites"."id" = "user_favorites"."favorite_id" WHERE "user_favorites"."user_id" = $1 AND "favorite"."color" = 'blue'"

Comment: @NothingToSeeHere Sorry I had a typo. In there where statement, it should be `favorites` (plural), because in the where, you're referencing the actual table's name (which is always plural in rails). Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly your `:blue` scope should look something like this:

```
scope :blue, -> { joins(:favorite).where(favorites: { color: 'blue' }) }
```

In the `joins` you have to use the association name while in the `where` clause you have to use the table name.

Comment: I am getting this error now "There is an Error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "favorite"
LINE 1: ...id" WHERE "user_favorites"."user_id" = $1 AND "favorite"."...
                                                             ^
: SELECT "user_favorites".* FROM "user_favorites" INNER JOIN "favorites" ON "favorites"."id" = "user_favorites"."favorite_id" WHERE "user_favorites"."user_id" = $1 AND "favorite"."color" = 'blue'"

Comment: Are you sure you are using the tablename in the where clause?